# Timer to continue when message box is shown

Tags: c#, wpf

I am looking to allow a timer to continue counting down even when a message box is shown. The message box is shown when the timer hits 30 seconds and zero seconds. However, currently the timer stops until the message box is closed by the user. My current code is below;

```
_Time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

_Timer = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), DispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate
    {
        O2_Timer.Text = _Time.ToString("c");
        if (_Time == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("timer is at 30 seconds");
        }
        if (_Time == TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            _Timer.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("timer done");
            Sub_Depth.Text = null;
        }
        _Time = _Time.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
    }, Application.Current.Dispatcher);

    _Timer.Start();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the answer not just don't call the stop method?

Comment: @Andy The stop method only occurs when the timer hits zero, I am looking to have it continue when the message is shown at 30 seconds.

Comment: I see. Messagebox is blocking. Dispatchertimer runs on ui thread. I think if you use one of the other timers instead then it'll still fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most effective thing would be to create a new thread and call it,
The Messagebox is blocking because its on the same thread if you will create and start a new thread it will work

```
_Time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
 //Creating a new thread
 Thread newMessage = new Thread(runThread);     

_Timer = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1),DispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate
  {
    O2_Timer.Text = _Time.ToString("c");
    if (_Time == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
    {
        //Starting the thread
        newMessage.Start();
    }
    if (_Time == TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
        _Timer.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("timer done");
        Sub_Depth.Text = null;
    }
    _Time = _Time.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
}, Application.Current.Dispatcher);

_Timer.Start();

private static void runThread(){
    //The thread function
    MessageBox.Show("timer is at 30 seconds");
}
```